# Stop thread execution when it calls url.openStream() in a loop

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt, interrupt-handling

**Edit**: I know what Thread.interrupt() does.

- `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` does not exit when I interrupt the thread.
- I also tried to catch an exception from url.openStream(); when the
  thread is interrupted (desperation, maybe it was a blocking method,
  which is not) and exit the loop, without any success.

The application creates a `Thread` that **continuously reads** a `URL`. After 3 seconds that `Thread` gets interrupted but unfortunately continues to execute.

How to **stop the thread** from executing?

*Code (Main.java, MyRunnable.java):*

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable("http://ninjaflex.com/");
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        sleep(3000);
        thread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thread.interrupt() invoked.");
    }

    private static void sleep(long timeMilli) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeMilli);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private String website;

    MyRunnable(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url = createUrl();
        if (url != null) {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                sleepOneSec();
                readFromUrl(url);
                System.out.println("Read from " + website);
            }
            System.out.println("Script: Interrupted, exiting.");
        }
    }

    private URL createUrl() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(website);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong URL?");
        }
        return url;
    }

    private void sleepOneSec() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error sleeping");
        }
    }

    private void readFromUrl(URL url) {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = url.openStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while url.openStream().");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeInputStream(in);
        }
    }

    private void closeInputStream(InputStream in) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing the input stream.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what Thread.interrupt() does dear @PM77-1, but If I did something wrong here please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your `MyRunnable` thread is interrupted during sleep. `InterreuptedException` is thrown but catched. By the way, it's a bad habit to catch `Exception` and you should not do that.
From the javadoc: "The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown".
Therefore, your while loop will never see the flag.

Comment: Oh I did not see that coming. Let me check by removing sleep. But that seems logical. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Ok I've missed that scenario: *"If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then **its interrupt status will be cleared** and it will receive an InterruptedException. "*. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the call to the `sleepOneSec` method with a simple Thread.sleep call.  Catch InterruptedException *outside* your `while` loop.  This will cause the loop to exit naturally:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        readFromUrl(url);
        System.out.println("Read from " + website);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Script: Interrupted, exiting.");
}
```

Comment: Yep, that will do. But I don't care removing the sleep call. To be honest I put it there so I don't get bombarded by logs.

Comment: Bombarded by "Script: Interrupted, exiting" you mean?  Just change it to `System.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(System.Logger.Level.DEBUG, "Script: Interrupted, exiting.", e);` so it’s only seen if you change the logging configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VGR!

Comment: Would you believe that I have the same piece of code in an android application, and the thread's execution is not stopping? Hint, there is no Thread.sleep() there. Probably will ask one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the MyRunnable.sleepOneSec and your code started to work.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. The sleep() was catching the interruption but then **the interrupt status was cleared** so the loop could not be exited.